# How to get urls of every image from this product URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

**Problem Description:**

Each product on this website https://www.asos.com/us/women/dresses/cat/?cid=8799 has several images. For instance, this is one product URL of a black dress https://www.asos.com/us/asos-design/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-black/prd/204910824#colourWayId-204910828, and if you click on it, you can see that there are 4 images for this black dress. Also, there are 2 other color versions of this dress (camel and pink). For each of these colors, there are another 3-4 images. I would like to collect all of these images (each image of the black, camel, and pink version of this product).

**What I tried (code below)**: So far, I have managed to collect all product URLS from the main page e.g aka 1 product URL = the 2nd link provided above. But, once I access each product URL, I cannot figure out how to access all the images inside this URL. I'd appreciate any guidance in realizing this next step.

Code from Google Colab:

```
# Upload google drive files
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
# Import libraries
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO 
# Make Soup function
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

def make_soup(url):
    request= urllib.request.Request(url, None,headers) 
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata
# Find total page #s
site = 'https://www.asos.com/us/women/dresses/cat/?cid=8799'
soup = make_soup(site)
element = soup.find('p', class_='label_Ph1fi')
element = element.text

numbers = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*', element)

if len(numbers) >= 2:
    offset = int(numbers[0].replace(',', ''))
    num_images = int(numbers[1].replace(',', ''))
    num_pages = int(num_images / offset)
    print(f"Images Per Page: {offset}")
    print(f"Total Images: {num_images}")
    print(f"Total Pages:{num_pages}")
else:
    print("Numbers not found")
#num_images = int(element.replace(',', '').split(' ')[0])
# Get all product urls 

product_urls = []
for i in range(num_pages):
    site = 'https://www.asos.com/us/women/dresses/cat/?cid=8799&page='
    site = site + str(i)
    soup = make_soup(site)
    a = soup.find_all('a',class_='productLink_E9Lfb',href=True)
    for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='productLink_E9Lfb', href=True):
                href = link.get('href')
                if href:
                    product_urls.append(href)
    print('Page ', i, ' done')

print(product_urls)

# Get all images per product url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
}


def get_data(html_source):
    data = re.search(r"window\.asos\.pdp\.config\.product = (.*);", html_source)
    data = json.loads(data.group(1))
    return data


def get_images(url):
    data = get_data(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)

    for i in data["images"]:
        print(f'{i["colour"]:<15} {i["url"]}')


base_url = "https://www.asos.com/us/asos-design/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-black/prd/204910824"
data = get_data(requests.get(base_url, headers=headers).text)

u = "https://www.asos.com/us/prd/"
for p in data["facetGroup"]["facets"][0]["products"]:
    get_images(u + str(p["productId"]))
```

Prints:

```
PINK            https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-light-pink/204910765-1-pink
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-light-pink/204910765-2
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-light-pink/204910765-3
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-light-pink/204910765-4
CAMEL           https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-camel/204910786-1-camel
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-camel/204910786-2
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-camel/204910786-3
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-camel/204910786-4
BLACK           https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-black/204910824-1-black
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-black/204910824-2
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-black/204910824-3
                https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-super-soft-volume-sleeve-turtle-neck-mini-sweater-dress-in-black/204910824-4
```

Comment: How did you learn how to do this? Did you take a course or have some online reference that you can share? I'd like to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Also, is there a way to implement the code I included in my post with "requests.get" instead of "beautifulsoup"? I'd like to keep my code consistent (one method only).

Comment: @Danny_webb You can safely use `beautifulsoup` for getting all product URLs and my code for getting all image URLs from the product links.  Whatever it needs to get job done :)

Comment: Any courses or references you recommend to learn how to do what you just did in your response?